# changing a color s a ggally ggparcoord plot in r

Tags: r, ggally

```
ggparcoord(data = df, columns = 1:4, mapping=aes(color=as.factor(Species)))+
  scale_color_discrete("Species",labels=levels(df$Species))
```

How do I change the standard colors of this plot to stesoa=black, versicolor=green, and virginica=mageanta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scale_color_manual()` to set custom colors:

```
ggparcoord(df,
           columns = 1:4,
           mapping = aes(color = as.factor(Species))) +
  scale_color_manual("Species",
                     values = c("black", "green", "magenta"),
                     labels = levels(df$Species))
```

[image: custom colors]